# Large MySQL Database back up ZURMO

Tags: mysql, database, mysqldump

Not sure if anyone if familiar with Zurmo. Long story short I need to back up the whole database for it. I would use PHPmyadmin but I didn't install it when I set up Ubuntu Server. I want to use MySQLdump command but I'm afraid of crashing the database since its 2GB. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

2Gb is not Large.

But, coincidentally, it is large enough to cause you problems with PHPMyAdmin depending on how your webserver is configured. Use mysqldump.

You didn't say why you want to extract the data - is this a one off migration exercise? Is this part of your DR capability? Is it so you can roll back a system to a known good state? All of which have implications for the backup solution.

Getting the data out of the database is only part of your problem though - you still need to get the data to where the backup will reside in the longer term. Can you run mysqldump at/near the place where the data will reside? If this is different from where the database is located then you may have problems connecting to the database - its rather silly to expose a raw database connection on the internet. A potential solution would be an ssh or ssl tunnel (but you didn't tell us anything about the operating systems at either end).

You also need to test restoring your database.

Answer (score 0):

I have 40Gb MySQL database with important data and this database must work without stopping for a minute.

To do backup I assigned this database as master and created slave database on other server. Now I can do backup from slave database during two hours via standard `mysqldump` command and slow connection.

Comment: Why don't you use mysql's async replication? It'll use a lot less bandwidth

Comment: @symcbean Replication is asynchronous by default. I have less bandwidth to backup server. Also I lock all tables before dumping them. It's needed to preserve relations between tables.